# Not sure how to use GradientDrawable perfectly

Tags: android, android-spinner, gradientdrawable

I have in an activity some inputs required to make a drawable shape. This is a little example of it:

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
gd.setColor(Color.RED);
gd.setCornerRadius(12);
preview.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
preview.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
preview.setBackground(gd);
```

But when I want to implement it into a spinner, I have to choose like all the options multiple times so I can get the result. And also there is a button which should show the preview, doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import yuku.ambilwarna.AmbilWarnaDialog;

public class CustomizationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int currentColor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customization);

    final EditText widthText = findViewById(R.id.width);
    final EditText heightText = findViewById(R.id.height);
    final Spinner shapeSpinner = findViewById(R.id.shape);
    final View colorView = findViewById(R.id.color);
    final View preview = findViewById(R.id.preview);
    final EditText size = findViewById(R.id.size);
    final EditText corners = findViewById(R.id.corners);
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    final GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();

    shapeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 1) {

                gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
                gd.setCornerRadius(Integer.parseInt(corners.getText().toString()));
                preview.getLayoutParams().width = Integer.parseInt(widthText.getText().toString());
                preview.getLayoutParams().height = Integer.parseInt(heightText.getText().toString());


            }

            if (position == 2) {

                gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);

                preview.getLayoutParams().width = Integer.parseInt(size.getText().toString());
                preview.getLayoutParams().height = Integer.parseInt(size.getText().toString());

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    colorView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(CustomizationActivity.this, currentColor, false, new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {

                    currentColor = color;

                    colorView.setBackgroundColor(color);

                    gd.setColor(color);

                }
            });

            dialog.show();

        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            preview.setBackground(gd);
        }
    });

}
```

}

It is somehow working but I don't know how to correct it. What I want is - if it possible - to show a preview directly when a value is changed. - And if not, after editing everything, get the result on button click.

I don't know but I think the problem is with the spinner.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call in your `onclick()` method after setting property call `gd.invalidateSelf();`

Comment: Nop still not working. I have to select an other option from the spinner and reselect what I want so the preview is changed